# How to do double interpolation in pug.js?

Tags: pug

I cannot double interpolate like this. Is there a way to double interpolate?
`p #{selected}  #{val.#{selectedraw}}`

val has an attribute dynamically selected when the user presses a select on a form.

so I need to double interpolate. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [*Interpolation* in Pug docs](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html):

> The code in between `#{` and `}` is evaluated, escaped, and the result buffered into the output of the template being rendered.
>
> This can be any valid Javascript expression, so you can do whatever feels good.

So, you can use the regular [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) as you would in JavaScript:

```
- const selected = 'foo'
- const selectedraw = 'bar'
- const val = { bar: 'ham', qux: 'spam' }

p #{selected} #{val[selectedraw]}
```

Output:

```html
<p>foo ham</p>
```

Comment: 1. I love you
2. I RTFM but I couldnt find that simple solution. :(

Comment: but can I do something like
```#{val.'away'[selectedraw]}```
???

I mean I want to connect a dynamic var like [selectedraw] with sometext, so that the final function gets created on the fly.

Comment: Are you looking for `#{val['away' + selectedraw]}`?